# dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.LimitsExceeded

Tags: linux, operating-system, raspbian, dbus

Using D-bus am trying to automatically connect raspberry pi with mobile through Bluetooth, it works fine for 265 times but again when I try I get an error

I created a file /etc/dbus-1/session-local.conf and added

```
<!DOCTYPE busconfig PUBLIC "-//freedesktop//DTD D-Bus Bus Configuration 1.0//EN"
 "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/dbus/1.0/busconfig.dtd">
<busconfig>
<limit name="max_replies_per_connection">1200</limit>
</busconfig>
```

But still am getting the same error

```
dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.LimitsExceeded: The maximum number of active connections for UID 1000 has been reached
devise doesnt exist
```

Can anyone let me know if there is anyway to change d-bus limits

Please help me out am new to it

Comment: What you say "Bluetooth, it works fine for 265 times", what does that mean? Does that mean you can connect 265 times and then on the 266th time it fails? Is something not getting closed when you disconnect? Do you have some code creating these connections to the mobile phone?